# Add # character forward in the every string character in Swift 4

Tags: swift, ascii

How can I achieve add 3 alphabets on every character of a string?
For example:

> Example No. 1: In a certain language ‘CSAT’ is coded as EUCV. How is ‘CIVIL’ written in that language?
> Sol: In this, all the letters in a word are moved two places forward.

How can I achieve the same in Swift? What I have tried so far is:

```
import UIKit

var str: String! = "abc"
let letter = "abcdefghijlklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var newstring = ""
func getlatestAddedString(arr: [Character]) -> String{
    for i in 0..<arr.count{
        //Logic goes here
        newstring = newstring + String(newchar)
    }
    
    return newstring
}

let arr = Array(str)
let newRevStr = getlatestAddedString(arr: arr)
print("Final output is \(newRevStr)")

let startChar = Unicode.Scalar("A").value
let endChar = Unicode.Scalar("Z").value
```

How can I achieve the same in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

```
let alphabet = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
let str = "CSAT"

let codedLetters: [Character] = Array(str).map { letter in
    let currentIndex = alphabet.firstIndex(where: {
        $0.lowercased() == letter.lowercased()
    })!

    let newIndex = (currentIndex + 2) % alphabet.count

    return alphabet[newIndex]
}

let result = String(codedLetters).uppercased()
print(result) //prints EUCV
```